# I am getting error while executing script from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh-keys

In jenkins pre-build step I select `Execute shell script on remote using ssh` while executing script I am getting below error

**cd /home/appsusr/bin; ./removetwl.sh**

```
[ssh] Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/appsusr/ .ssh/id_dsa (No such file directory)
com.Jcraft.jsch.JschException:java.io.filenotfoundexception: /home/aapsusr/ .ssh/id_dsa (no such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there somewhere you're specifying the path to your SSH key? Looks like you have an extra space before `.ssh`.

Comment: There is no extra space before .ssh